# EF Core 3.1 - Sql server IN operator translation (without AsEnumerable()/ToList())

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-3.0

I have just done the upgrade from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.1. I have some queries like this:

```
...
userIdList.All(u => _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ContextOwnerCode == t.ContextOwnerCode && x.CompanyCode == u.CompanyCode && x.ConversationId == t.Id && x.UserId == u.ElementId &&
                            (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) && (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted)) > 0) &&
                    _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ConversationId == t.Id && (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) &&
                        (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted) && userIdList.Count(u => u.CompanyCode == x.CompanyCode && u.ElementId == x.UserId) == 0) == 0)
...
```

here the userIdList is a list that needs to be compared with data in the database. With EF Core 3 this function is no more translated.

One solution could be to use AsEnumerable() or ToList() but in my case is not a good solution since I have a huge amount of data and it is not possible to get all the data on the client side.

**EDIT**

This is the full query:

```
var result = _context.Conversations.Where(t => t.ContextOwnerCode == contextOwnerCode &&
                ((docYear == 0 && docCode == 0) ||
                    (docYear != 0 && docCode != 0 && t.DocumentYear != null && t.DocumentCode != null && t.DocumentYear == docYear && t.DocumentCode == docCode)) &&
                (
                (senderGroup != null && senderGroup.CompanyCode > 0 && senderGroup.ElementId > 0 && recipientGroup != null && recipientGroup.CompanyCode > 0 && recipientGroup.ElementId > 0 &&
                    (userIdList == null || userListCount == 0) &&
                    t.CreatedChatGroupId != null && t.ChatGroupId != null && t.CreatedChatGroupId > 0 && t.ChatGroupId > 0 &&
                    ((senderGroup.CompanyCode == t.CreatedCompanyCode && senderGroup.ElementId == t.CreatedChatGroupId &&
                    recipientGroup.CompanyCode == t.ChatGroupCompanyCode && recipientGroup.ElementId == t.ChatGroupId) ||
                    (senderGroup.CompanyCode == t.ChatGroupCompanyCode && senderGroup.ElementId == t.ChatGroupId &&
                    recipientGroup.CompanyCode == t.CreatedCompanyCode && recipientGroup.ElementId == t.CreatedChatGroupId))) ||
                (((senderGroup != null && senderGroup.CompanyCode > 0 && senderGroup.ElementId > 0 &&
                        (recipientGroup == null || (recipientGroup.CompanyCode == 0 && recipientGroup.ElementId == 0))) ||
                    ((senderGroup == null || (senderGroup.CompanyCode == 0 && senderGroup.ElementId == 0)) &&
                        recipientGroup != null && recipientGroup.CompanyCode > 0 && recipientGroup.ElementId > 0)) &&
                    userIdList != null && userListCount > 0 &&
                    ((senderGroup != null && t.CreatedChatGroupId != null && t.ChatGroupCompanyCode == null && t.ChatGroupId == null &&
                            senderGroup.CompanyCode == t.CreatedCompanyCode && senderGroup.ElementId == t.CreatedChatGroupId) ||
                        (recipientGroup != null && t.CreatedChatGroupId == null && t.ChatGroupCompanyCode != null && t.ChatGroupId != null &&
                            recipientGroup.CompanyCode == t.ChatGroupCompanyCode && recipientGroup.ElementId == t.ChatGroupId)) &&
                    userIdList.All(u =>
                        _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ContextOwnerCode == t.ContextOwnerCode && x.CompanyCode == u.CompanyCode && x.ConversationId == t.Id && x.UserId == u.ElementId &&
                            (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) && (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted)) > 0) &&
                    _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ConversationId == t.Id && (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) &&
                        (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted) && userIdList.Count(u => u.CompanyCode == x.CompanyCode && u.ElementId == x.UserId) == 0) == 0) ||
                ((senderGroup == null || (senderGroup.CompanyCode == 0 && senderGroup.ElementId == 0)) &&
                    recipientGroup != null && recipientGroup.CompanyCode > 0 && recipientGroup.ElementId > 0 &&
                    (userIdList == null || userListCount == 0) &&
                    t.CreatedChatGroupId == null && t.ChatGroupCompanyCode != null && t.ChatGroupId != null &&
                    recipientGroup.CompanyCode == t.ChatGroupCompanyCode && recipientGroup.ElementId == t.ChatGroupId &&
                    _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ConversationId == t.Id && (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) && (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted)) == 0) ||
                ((senderGroup == null || (senderGroup.CompanyCode == 0 && senderGroup.ElementId == 0)) &&
                    (recipientGroup == null || (recipientGroup.CompanyCode == 0 && recipientGroup.ElementId == 0)) &&
                    userIdList != null && userListCount > 1 &&
                    userIdList.All(u =>
                        _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ContextOwnerCode == t.ContextOwnerCode && x.CompanyCode == u.CompanyCode && x.ConversationId == t.Id && x.UserId == u.ElementId &&
                            (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) && (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted)) > 0) &&
                    _context.ConversationUsers.Count(x => x.ConversationId == t.Id && (x.GroupId == null || x.GroupId == 0) &&
                        (x.Deleted == null || !(bool)x.Deleted) && userIdList.Count(u => u.CompanyCode == x.CompanyCode && u.ElementId == x.UserId) == 0) == 0)
                )
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I would say that most likely if it is not translated now, it was not before. In 2.2 it was executed silently on client side, cause by default untranslatable queries where executed client side (and no throwing exception like in 3).

Comment: @GuruStron I am not sure EF Core 3.x translates everything EF Core 2.2 did, but in this case (nested `Count`) it definitely did not and did client side evaluation.

Comment: Firstly, @GuruStron is write, EF Core 2.2 was most likely doing client side evaluation after translating as much as it could handle. So, translate the `Count(x)` into `Where(x).Count()` each time, then split the `x` lambda on the `&&` into two `Where` and then put `AsEnumerable()` before the untranslatable part, which is essentially what EF Core 2.2 would attempt.

Comment: Your code has a parenthesis mismatch in it somewhere, I can't try to translate or figure it out - please try to correct it.

Comment: I have just update the full query.
So, if I understood, in EF Core 2.2 the AsEnumerable() was implicit instead in 3 I need to specify it, in any case the huge amount of data would be downloaded client side anyway. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation here is to convert the above query to [SQL Store Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15).

> There is a good tool called [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) you can use to make the conversion easier.

P.S. in the above code you can try to use `!Any(...)` method instead of `Count(...) == 0`.